# Encryption and Decryption in Java Card

Tags: arrays, encryption, cryptography, javacard

I am using the following code to Encrypt and Decrypt data in Javacard:

```
private byte[] hello = {'h','e','l','l','o','1','2','3'};
private byte []encryptedData = new byte[8];  
private void encrypt(byte[] dataToEncrypt){
    try{
            byte []inputData = dataToEncrypt;    
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.ALG_DES_CBC_ISO9797_M1, false);    
            DESKey desKey = (DESKey)KeyBuilder.buildKey(KeyBuilder.TYPE_DES,KeyBuilder.LENGTH_DES,false);     
            byte [] keyBytes = {(byte)0x01,(byte)0x02,(byte)0x03,(byte)0x04, (byte)0x05,(byte)0x06,(byte)0x07,(byte)0x08};
            desKey.setKey(keyBytes, (short)0);   
            cipher.init(desKey, Cipher.MODE_ENCRYPT);    
            cipher.doFinal(inputData, (short)0, (short)inputData.length, encryptedData,(short)0);   
 showMessage(encryptedData);
       }
    catch(CryptoException e){        
 }
 }

private byte []decryptedData = new byte[8];  
private void decrypt(byte[] dataToDecrypt){
    try{
            byte []outputData = dataToDecrypt;   
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.ALG_DES_CBC_ISO9797_M1, false);    
            DESKey desKey = (DESKey)KeyBuilder.buildKey(KeyBuilder.TYPE_DES,KeyBuilder.LENGTH_DES,false);     
            byte [] keyBytes = {(byte)0x01,(byte)0x02,(byte)0x03,(byte)0x04, (byte)0x05,(byte)0x06,(byte)0x07,(byte)0x08};
            desKey.setKey(keyBytes, (short)0);   
            cipher.init(desKey, Cipher.MODE_DECRYPT);    
            cipher.doFinal(outputData, (short)0, (short)outputData.length, decryptedData,(short)0); 
            showMessage(decryptedData);
       }
   catch(CryptoException e){         
}
}

encrypt(hello);
decrypt(encryptedData);
```

Whenever I try to encrypt an object which is of size 8 byte everything works fine. But whenever the size of the object to be encrypted is anything else, it doesn't work. I believe there is some issue of padding. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Just guessing: is your `encryptedData` array long enough to hold the padded ciphertext aligned to block size of DES? You should always have a look at `CryptoExcetion.getReason()` in your catch blocks; it could help you to find the source of your problem.

Comment: Thnaks a lot. Your comment solved my problem.

Comment: @AdityaParsai  Just another comment... be aware that you are creating cipher, desKey, keyBytes on every call to the functions decrypt and encrypt. In Java Card there is no garbage collector and this may lead to memory problems.

Comment: @jlanza if I keep cipher, desKey, keyBytes outside the function will it be ok?